# Android TabWidget without TabHost with custom actions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

Is possible to use TabWidget without TabHost? I wanna something like Tabs navigation for ActionBar failback for older phones.

So I only want to show user tabs and listen on click actions, where I get active tab ID. Nothing more.

I know in common situations TabsNavigatin for actionBar is just for navigate through Fragments. But I easily avoid Fragments. :

```
class mTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Screen screen;

    public mTabListener(Screen screen) {
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        screen.onTabReselected(tab, ft);
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        screen.onTabSelected(tab, ft);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        screen.onTabUnselected(tab, ft);
    }

}


public abstract class Screen extends Activity {    
protected void addTab(String title, int what, boolean selected) {
    if (Global.API < 11)
        return;

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    Tab tab = bar.newTab()
        .setTag(new Integer(what))
        .setTabListener(new mTabListener(this))
        .setText(title);

    bar.addTab(tab, selected);
}

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Integer what = (Integer)tab.getTag();
        tabSelected(what);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public void tabSelected(int what) {

    }
}
```

But I can't find how to add tab buttons to TabWidget;

Answer (score 0):

No. Tab widget without tab host is like using pushbutton for the tabs. You will have do the manipulation of tab navigation.

Comment: This is exactly I want. I don't need multiple activities, I just need Tab control (which controls my own component)

Comment: Well, just drops some push butons and listen to its events like focus, click and then manipulate the views. I think you can use Tabhost for your purpose rather than reimplementing the samething.

Comment: I don't need manipulate the views. I need change some info and I must keep standard look&feel. One way is to reinvent wheel and make my own TabsWidget, who is more adaptable. But maybe there is more easier way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, TabWidget without tabHost

https://github.com/muratonnet/android-SingleTabWidget